# Pandas Series: How to get the nth non-zero element before each element

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have a pandas series like this:

```
[0,3,4,5,0,0,2,4,5]
```

For each element, I want to be able to get the nth non-zero element before it.

The output Series for the above input Series would be

```
n=1
[NaN,NaN,3,4,5,5,5,2,4]

n=2
[NaN,NaN,NaN,3,4,4,4,5,2]
```

etc.

Is there a built in way in pandas to do this easily?

Comment: maybe using http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/generated/pandas.Series.nonzero.html, but it's not immediate....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use rolling and apply to extract the nth non zero elements from the rolling window.

First we use rolling(len(s)) which gives a rolling 9 rows window until the current row for each row. Then we remove 0s from the rolling window. x[:-1] is to exclude the current row because we need to find the non-zero element before it. Finally, we extract the nth element from the non-zero list by doing [-n].

```
n=1
s.rolling(len(s),min_periods=0)\
 .apply(lambda x: x[:-1][x[:-1]!=0][-n] if len(x[:-1][x[:-1]!=0])>=n else np.nan)
Out[97]: 
0    NaN
1    NaN
2    3.0
3    4.0
4    5.0
5    5.0
6    5.0
7    2.0
8    4.0
dtype: float64

n=2    
s.rolling(len(s),min_periods=0)\
 .apply(lambda x: x[:-1][x[:-1]!=0][-n] if len(x[:-1][x[:-1]!=0])>=n else np.nan)
Out[99]: 
0    NaN
1    NaN
2    NaN
3    3.0
4    4.0
5    4.0
6    4.0
7    5.0
8    2.0
dtype: float64
```

Comment: This seems to be working. The code seems rather complex. Can you please explain what is happening in the code?

Comment: @ishan3243, I've added a bit comments in the code. Let me know if it helps.

Answer (score -1):

```
def dew(zoop, n):
  x = zoop.pop()
  zoop.reverse()
  for i in range(len(zoop)):
    if not zoop[i] == 0:
      n -= 1
      if n == 0:
        return zoop[i]
  return float('NaN')

lzt = [0,3,4,5,0,0,2,4,5]
ans = []
for i in range(len(lzt)):
  ans.append(dew(lzt[:i+1], 2)) #2 is n here
```

Comment: This does not use any inbuilt pandas functions. The question specifically asks for it.

Comment: Is this down voted for lack of explanation? Or for the errors it used to have? Edit: ahh thats why. Okie doke